# How is the CoC about to change?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

In [this discussion](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193), ex-moderator Monica Cellio describes a change to the Code of Conduct:

> A director had dropped into the room to announce an upcoming change to the Code of Conduct; unlike the rest of the CoC, **this rule mandates specific, positive actions.** I raised some issues with the formation of the policy and asked some questions, the vast majority of which were never answered. I was polite and was trying to work with others to solve a problem I have with the change as presented.

Emphasis added. I encourage everyone to click through and read the entire post; I have deliberately elided nearly all of it to focus on one specific point.

**What are the specific positive actions which moderators will soon be required to take?**

This is not a demand that the CM team explain what happened to Monica. I already know that the CM team likely will not offer an explanation, and that demand already [lives here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/275243) anyway. So I'm not asking for an explanation. Instead, I'm focusing on the part of the question that I think the CM team will be willing to answer.

Comment: The CoC applies to all of us and as it hasn't changed yet, is there anything we can do except speculate? I assume any mod that shares the new /changed articles are likely to be demoted and/or banned when they share.

Comment: @rene: I'm asking for Stack Exchange-the-company to answer this question now, rather than springing the change on us later. Hopefully, they will at least be willing to go that far, even if they maintain that Monica "violated" some rule.

Comment: It...wait for it...hasn't actually changed yet! Odd, eh?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Clarified the wording a bit (future tense for future events).

Comment: Having heard some vague context from a mod, "something big" is going to happen, and there's going to be an announcement in the next couple weeks. I have no idea what those changes are, but you can at the very least expect an answer some time in a couple weeks, but I doubt there's gonna be more.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia: They don't have a couple weeks. The Workplace is down to two mods. In a couple weeks, there may be sites with *no* mods.

Comment: @Kevin I know. This situation has the potential to royally screw up multiple sites in the network. And yes, there will be sites without mods. If there's one unfortunate thing I've learned in the past couple of weeks, it's that SE probably won't care. They'll ignore it and take care of it in 6-8 arbitrary time units. This is extremely urgent, but won't be prioritized as such.

Comment: That being said, provided enough pressure, something might be done. Worked for the welcoming wagon anyway. Which is why it's good these posts exist. Now they just need more attention.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia: Read [this](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/resignation-notice), and I think you can put two and two together.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've read all of them. I made a filter earlier today to catch all [discussion] posts posted on metas around the network (which should cover all properly tagged resignations). I also posted a tweet in an attempt to get more attention to that specific post, because I can't with good consciousness let it remain hidden on a child meta and get little to no attention (also because SE, in the past, has responded more when they get stuff targeting them on Twitter).

Comment: @Kevin workplace is down by 3 mods (from the 5 it had a few days ago).  Monica was fired.  Snow and Jane S have both quit in protest.  Under normal circumstances I would expect an election to be started tomorrow.  Now though... ????

Comment: @DanNeely: "Down to two" means they have two left. 5 - 3 = 2, so I'm not sure what your point is?

Comment: While I sympathize and respect the motivation for this post, my belief is that SE was going to post about the CoC changes anyway, either on the blog or here or both. I don’t think this request will accelerate that. I think the delay is in SE trying to frame the change and choosing their words carefully. Especially if they post on meta, they’re going to have to tap dance around making the change seem to support both the welcoming initiative & the veteran users’ interests. Then, this post might be more useful in getting ahead of that framing & asking pointed Qs about how it protects the veterans

Comment: @DanBron: I am intentionally keeping this as neutrally worded as possible because I do not want to get into a shouting match with people who have a demonstrated history of [taking their collective ball and going home](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387633/1340389) when they are criticized in public. If you want to ask "pointed Qs about how it protects the veterans," please do so in a separate question.

Comment: @Kevin Ok, but all I’m saying is this Q is superfluous. They would have posted such an announcement whether this Q was asked or not, and this Q won’t accelerate their response. If you’re going to ask such a Q, might as well ask one that will elicit information we would not have gotten otherwise. My $.02.

Comment: @SaraChipps - Execute Order 66! I will start submitting requests to remove my accounts from all the other sites. I did it for Stack Overflow because I no longer wanted to be associated with the damage that site was doing to my chosen profession. I do not want to be associated with anything they are doing at this point.

Comment: @Kevin [This](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718) sheds a little bit of light. Seems to have something to do with SE enforcing the use of proper pronouns for gender non-binary people.

Comment: @Geronimo: While I can understand where that is coming from, quoting a poem about Nazi Germany in relation to gender pronoun usage seems a bit excessive to me. I have to wonder if this would've been such a big deal if they just would've had a little more transparency around the whole thing...

Comment: @Kevin yes, that part seems a bit out of context. Though I do sympathize with the disagreement to mandate communication in such an exact fashion from volunteers (to the level of enforcing what pronouns can be used, not just "be nice"). And also that non-communication would be considered a violation of CoC.

Comment: @Geronimo: This is grayer than many people are willing to admit, on both sides. Obviously, if someone tells you they are a man, or a woman, you're going to take their word for it; there are no genital inspections in real life, much less on the internet. So the question is whether we force trans individuals to hide their trans-ness in order to benefit from that assumption, or we force everyone else to use the preferred pronouns of openly trans people. Reasonable people will object to each of those alternatives, but I see no third way.

Comment: (That's not to say, however, that we should adhere to some kind of [golden mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_to_moderation). Indeed, my entire *point* is that one side has to win and the other has to lose. I'd prefer not to let this descend too far into politics, so I won't state my preference here, but I do have one.)

Comment: @Kevin well stated, I prefer to stay unpolitical also. In that light however wouldn't a third way be obviating _force_ from the context? In other words: _not_ forcing the hiding and _not_ forcing the recognition though of course, continuing to force the non-descrimination policy.

Comment: @Geronimo: Then you're presenting trans people with the rather unfair choice of hiding their trans-ness or accepting deliberate mis-gendering from others. That's still a form of coercion ("Hide, or we'll be nasty to you.").

Comment: For additional context: as a member of a minority in other fronts I appreciate recognition sometimes but personally I would feel obtuse demanding it and enforcing it on others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1357/discussion-between-geronimo-and-kevin).

Comment: This question is a bit premature. Without an official statement, nobody will know for sure.

Comment: If it's all only about some language usage, I must say, that I have problems understanding how such a thing can explode so much. It must have been some really bad kind of handling or some rather dictatorial elements in the planned CoC. Otherwise I would be happy to call anyone the way he or she or they like most and I guess most others would do the same.

Comment: [This article](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) on theregister.co.uk has a statement, allegedly coming from a "company spokesperson":

_Asked to confirm that Cellio was the moderator in question, a company
spokesperson said, "Cellio (she/her) would not use stated pronouns,
which violates our current CoC. We are soon publishing an update to
the CoC to even more explicitly cite misgendering users or moderators
as a violation."_

Comment: Kevin, regarding "Hide, or we'll be nasty to you," I speak as the member of a minority group that faces an intense amount of hatred, bigotry and vitriol (from a tiny nasty vocal minority) any time I "out" myself in an internet discussion (including on SE).  Like @Geronimo, I appreciate respect, but true respect comes first from *understanding.*

Comment: Either the irony of the phonetics of the **C**ode **o**f **C**onduct acronym was lost on everyone (indicating a disappointingly high level of maturity among SE users), or a lot of comments were moderated out that we will never see. I'm guessing the latter.

Answer (score 47):

Caleb [posted the following](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/43210) to Christianity.SE's meta (excerpted):

> Personally I have yet to face the specific issue [pronouns], nobody to my knowledge has taken offense at the pronouns I used for them. But the "law" laid down quite suddenly and directly to moderators by several staff members was that **henceforth we all had to do whatever was requested of us.** It used to be that the ground rules were limited to a "be nice" policy that could have been boiled down to "if you can't say something nice don't say anything at all", and how that was enforced varied a bit by site. Even though I often disagree with the world at large on what is considered nice and constructive, I can usually figure out how to live within a system with boundaries. You can do X, but not Y. Given the framework of this secular platform those were rules I could play by.
>
> What changed is this: **now it isn't enough to not be rude to people you disagree with, the new policy forces us to positively affirm things we don't agree with. Even disengaging has been ruled out as an allowable solution, since that's discrimination and potentially hurtful.** That avoidance of potentially compromising scenarios is not allowed has been directly affirmed by staff members several times over the weekend.
>
> **If person A comes along and demands that I refer to them by their "preferred pronoun"** (even if it is a mismatch for their genetic sex or the grammar of the language being spoken) **and I refuse, that's considered an insult. Now if I avoid pronouns altogether by sticking to proper names or disengaging from the individual, that's being considered an insult too.**

I have added emphasis in a few places to focus on what the actual policy is. I do not endorse Caleb's opinion; this answer is strictly a factual description of what the new policy is. Anyone wanting to discuss *whether this policy is a Good Idea*, please ask a separate question.

Finally, my read of this, in a slightly more neutral tone of voice:

- Use of a person's preferred pronouns will be required.
- Deliberately avoiding trans people, or using their names instead of pronouns, will be disallowed.
- Moderators will (probably?) be required to enforce these rules against regular users.

As multiple people have pointed out in the comments, **we don't know for sure that this is accurate or complete.** However, I've seen several other moderators talk about this in more vague terms on other metas, and I've not yet seen anyone directly contradict the above summary.

Comment: This is an interpretation. Until we see the actual written changes, we don’t know what they will be, other than something related to using someone’s preferred pronouns.

Comment: If you're aiming for complete neutrality, you might change "I do not endorse Caleb's opinion" to "I do not endorse nor denounce Caleb's opinion," or just "I am not using this post to express agreement nor disagreement with Caleb's opinion."

Comment: @Wildcard: Sorry, but I'm not entirely comfortable saying that. This is as neutral as I'm willing to write it.

Comment: @user9161: I think Caleb's writing is fairly explicit, but the truth is we won't know anything until they publish the final wording.

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this comment here too: This change is in itself intended to be good, but it's dragged too far by disallowing the use of names. There's no reasonable arguments to support that. The idea is good, but the execution is bad.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia I can see why suddenly switching from pronouns to names after one's preferred pronoun has been learned could be quite noticeable and offending.

Comment: @JohnDvorak I can't imagine every single conversation starting with a pronoun introduction. Unless there's a system (a real system) to somehow display it to the same degree as the username, pronouns won't come up in most cases. But if you stick to names constantly, there's no switch. the example you mentioned is very context-dependent.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia agreed, but I suppose that policy is for cases where the pronoun is known to the moderator. I don't know if they're supposed to dig through transcripts (I hope not) or if it refers primarily to chat. But whatever system is in place for tracking X ongoing parallel conversations, adding a pronoun box to it to be filled as data comes naturaly would be an easy task from the technical standpoint.

Comment: @JohnDvorak yeah. There's still the grey zone for people who don't state their pronouns at all though.

Comment: If one side insists on one pronoun, and the other side insists on the other, then using a name instead of a pronoun would seem like neutral ground.  But apparently the new Code of Conduct is not going to allow neutral ground.  It is going to enforce one side of this contentious issue and punish the other side.

Comment: @Kyralessa That’s speculation based on chat, where announcements of unwritten policy changes should not be made for exactly this reason. It’s not because anyone has actually seen the changes yet.

Comment: @user9161 * shrug *  Where information is withheld, rumor jumps in to fill the void.

Comment: @Kyralessa Sure, I was just pointing out it was rumor and not fact.

Comment: @user9161: Clarified that this is speculative for now.

Comment: Can someone give a reason how or why anyone would not respect someone's wish to be referred to by a certain pronoun while at the same time they don't want to be disrespectful? Cause switching pronouns is literally a 0-effort thing.

Comment: @user9161, **"If language matters that much to you, it’s not reasonable to say it doesn’t matter to someone else."**  This statement is pure gold and cuts to the heart of the entire issue about gender pronouns.  Thank you, I'm saving this.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, ignoring when someone else refers to you by the wrong pronoun (especially when it is not malicious) is also "literally a 0-effort thing" which should help you question the assumptions that went into your comment.  I for one will never integrate the invented pronouns "xe, xyr, xim" into my speech or writing.  Attempts to legislate or regulate language are actually disguised attempts to regulate thought.  Look up "Newspeak."  This is *not intended* as an offense against any person.  It is about freedom of thought.  In order to be able to think, you have to risk being offensive.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, if someone insists on being referred to using Spivak pronouns, or xe/xem/xyr, or other uncommon pronouns, I would prefer to adjust my writing to avoid the use of third-person pronouns.  Not because I want to be offensive, but because I want my writing to be easily understood by people who read it.  (I already do this when I'm uncertain of the subject's gender, because it draws fewer objections from grammatical prescriptivists than singular "they" does.)

Comment: @SteffenWinkler you felt comfortable deliberately misgendering me (something I HAVE NOT done to anyone), thereby proving my point that it is necessary to be able to risk offense in order to express your ideas in some cases.  Under the Orwellian policies you have commented in vague support of, you could be suspended from the site for that.  In Canada you could be fired.  By your own admission you have disrespected me individually, which violates the Code of Conduct.  Do I care?  No.  But you have proven your position inconsistent.

Comment: @Mark I can see your point in relation to answering a question or commenting on one, since other people should be able to read and understand it as well. Meanwhile we are on the internet and people make up nicknames by which they want to be called all the time and generally people accept that. How is this any different?

Comment: @Wildcard oh, did I? I'm very sorry about that. But nice of you to try and think that I'm 'deliberately' doing something. And please read up what Orwell was about. Hint: it had nothing, absolutely nothing, to do with free speech. Also: Free speech is something between you and your governemnt. Last time I checked SE/SO was just a company, not a government. And why are we talking about Canada now? Could you maybe stop trying to derail the issue and come up with a good explanation on why you don't respect people's choices?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler two questions for you: (1) whose choice have I disrespected? (2) why don’t you respect my choice?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler incidentally, I have not written “free speech” even once in this conversation.  I wrote “freedom of thought.”  Which is very much to the point of 1984, thought police and Newspeak.  (Nor do I need to “read what Orwell was about” as I actually read his books in full.)

Comment: @Wildcard 1) you are talking about disrespecting someone's choice to be called a certain way 2) what choice would that be? Honest question. You have been talking all this time about the concept of free speech and how it is apparently neccessary to offend and aggrevate others to be able to do proper thinking.

Meanwhile all I'm asking is why it is so difficul for you to respect others. Which you still haven't even attempted to answer.

Comment: And you know what the most bizarre thing is? I don't even care about identity politics or have any involvement with LGBT people. I only care about people respecting eachother and if that means you call someone xxXUnicorn2020Xxx then so be it and that has always been done on the internet. We call that having nicknames. Why people make such a deal about pronouns now when we have been referring to eachother all this time by made up names - I don't understand.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler (1) again, whose choice have I disrespected?  Name one person, please.  (2) You are disrespecting my choice to decide for myself which words I wish to utter or write, without compulsion.  Also my choice to reject a linguistic invention that I find overbearing and offensive.  (Note I have never claimed that choice of words must always be without consequence.  You must face that regardless of what words you use, you CANNOT make a statement that is offensive to no one.  You are clearly willing to offend me with your remarks, yes?)

Comment: @Wildcard 1) you are talking about wanting to disrespect someone's choice. Constantly. This entire thread is about you wanting to offend someone by disrespecting their choice. 2) I didn't forbid you from saying anything. Even if I were, why would you care about that? You clearly believe that words don't have consequences. In the last part of your comment you are contradicting everything you said through this entire comment chain. Get a grip on what your actual stance is before entering a discussion. Either you want to be a disrespectful person on a public and semi-professional platform or not.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler thank you, I see you recognize you are unable to name a single person whose choice I have disrespected.

Comment: @Wildcard Oh, so you do respect that someone might want to be adressed by a specific gender or name? In that case: Why are you again opposed to a rule that says exactly that? You seem to be very confused about what this discussion is about.

Comment: @Kevin but you've exposed yourself as being against Caleb's position. Which is fine but it's not a neutral position and you can stop fooling around with this "i'm neutral" nonsense.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler if you don’t object to saying “please” and “thank you”, how could you *possibly* have any objection to **a law which established penalties** if you don’t say those things?

Comment: @SteffenWinkler: Policing pronouns has nothing whatsoever to do with respect.

Comment: @Wildcard but that isn't what is happening here. That analogy doesn't work. This is about replacing one word ('his') with another ('her') or vice versa. Your analogy requires the use of an extra word. Also can you not just answer a question by answering it instead of constantly counter-asking? Also: Again this isn't about laws. This is about rules on a website. Stop making this a larger issue than it really is.

Comment: @JamesKPolk it can in certain contexts. If a person asks you if you could address them as 'him' instead of 'her' and you choose to not do that and continue to use 'her' you _are_ being disrespectful. It is similiar to a situation where someone has a forename and a middlename and the person asks you to use their middlename. If you continue to use their forename you are being disrespectful and I hope we can at least agree on that.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler here is my answer: because you cannot achieve respect by legislation; because attempting to do so is destructive; and because attempting to replace living beings with fixed rules (e.g. “the receptionist must always smile at the customer”) will never be anything but destructive.  You are arguing about the wisdom of this particular idea about pronouns; I am arguing that *replacing a living being with a fixed idea* is never good no matter what the idea is.

Comment: "because you cannot achieve respect by legislation" agreed. "because attempting to do so is destructive" debatable in my opinion, but I can see what you mean. " and because attempting to replace living beings with fixed rules" not sure what you mean. Or to what degree you mean it. "You are arguing about the wisdom of this particular idea about pronouns" ah, to clarify: Until this happened I had no idea about any of these pronoun games and stuff and that it affects people. I still don't feel strong about _this_ particular 'thing'. What I care about is people respecting people...

Comment: ...and if someone wishes that I only use written communication, or only verbal communication or that they wish to be called 'Misses' instead of 'Mister' than that is a small, 0-effort thing I, or rather everyone, can do. There is no excuse to not do it (as it is doesn't cost you any effort) and because of that if someone chooses to go against that choice it is a deliberate and malicious choice. At least that is my line of thought. As such I don't understand why anyone would be upset about a rule clarifying this.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler: No, that is not disrespectful in any way. Respect means something, and it doesn't mean what you're implying. Mind you, I would absolutely use whatever pronouns the other person wanted me to use, but that should be my choice.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler: "effort" is completely irrelevant here. Also inferring malice from refusal to use a certain pronoun is exactly the kind of evidence-free determination we are up in arms about. Monica Cellio is **not** guilty of malice.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, thanks for your response.  James is correct.  It's not really about going against someone's wishes.  It's about *mandating* conformance to someone's wishes.  They are two vastly different things.  It doesn't matter how little effort is involved.  Now that I re-read your *original* comment, I see that you weren't actually asking about a *rule* but about why someone wouldn't want to comply with a polite request to use particular pronouns.  Which is a separate matter, and a less contentious one.

Comment: @James that reads like you are confusing respecting someone with having respect of or for someone. AS for the 0 effort part: if something isn't without effort i can understand why someone doesn't do something without further explanation. However if something is effortless - like holding open a door for the next person - a different reason is needed to not do it.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler: Nonbinary pronouns are actually a *lot* of effort until you've had a good deal of practice -- and what's more, they're a lot of effort both for the writer/speaker and for the reader/listener. (Consider the sentence "Marion said they're coming tomorrow." Did you understand that "they" refers to the same person as "Marion", and not to someone else that you're supposed to figure out from context? And *they* is at least recognizable as a pronoun; some nonbinary folks prefer words such as *ze* or *ou*. I don't see how you can claim that that requires zero effort.)

Comment: @ruakh I will freely admit that I don't 'get' non-binary people. That however doesn't hinder me from respecting their choice and if they would like to be adressed by a new pronoun then so be it. Languages change, and although this feels like a hastened change it doesn't matter. As for the sentence you mentioned above: 'they're' can refer to both, yes. That however has always been the case although one was way less likely. It may be that that feels more normal to me as my primary language uses that construct naturally as a way to address someone in a formal way.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler: Re: "That however has always been the case although one was way less likely": That is simply not true. Until recently, singular *they* was never used for a specific, known, identified person. (It could even be used if the gender was known -- but not if the identity was known.) And for the vast majority of speakers, that's still the case. Yes, language can change, but it's idle to claim that this requires no effort. And different nonbinary folks want different changes (though singular definite *they* seems to be winning out).

Comment: @SteffenWinkler, if you think that consistently using *he/him/his* and *she/her/her* in reference to the same person in the same sentence is zero-effort then you're already a better speaker of English than many people I interact with. In their defence, their native languages rarely use pronouns at all, and some of the pronouns they do use are epicene.

Comment: @ruakh unless you're mother tounge is one where there are no gendered pronouns. I find it really hard to always have to think about whether someone is a he, she, xe or whatever, since this was of no concern of me in my native language. For me the usage of they is the only easy way to talk, as that is the closest equivalent to whatever I used when I grew up speaking in my own language

Comment: @SztupY: Firstly -- what I said is that nonbinary pronouns are a lot of effort *until you've had a great deal of practice*. You're saying you've been practicing your whole life, so great, they're easy for you, but that doesn't affect my point. Secondly -- the new CoC apparently requires you to use the *correct* pronouns (when known). So you could get in trouble if you used "they" for someone who prefers "he". (And in fact, "they" has occasionally been used as an intentionally-rude way to avoid affirming a transman or transwoman's declared gender.)