# Stack Exchange staff speaking to the press instead of the community

Tags: discussion, support, community

The Register's [recent article](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) contains a comment from a company spokesperson:

> Asked to confirm that Cellio was the moderator in question, a company spokesperson said, "Cellio (she/her) would not use stated pronouns, which violates our current CoC. We are soon publishing an update to the CoC to even more explicitly cite misgendering users or moderators as a violation."

To the best of my knowledge, this quote provides more detail than SE employees have provided anywhere on Meta. In contrast (and setting aside the lack of communication on licensing and other recent issues to focus just on this one):

- Questions like [How is the CoC about to change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333967/how-is-the-coc-about-to-change) have not been answered by SE staff.
- [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) has gone unanswered, not even a "we'll get back to you."
- The boilerplate [message](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5197) posted underneath resignations says merely "We aren’t going to share specifics out of respect for all individuals involved," a position that seems incongruous with the spokesperson's comments to The Register
- [Aza's resignation](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/resignation-notice), which charges that community managers have failed to take action and that "moratoria are placed on speaking of our transness among moderators," was met with no response (excepting, in a different location, [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/334012#comment1090971_334012), which I appreciate), not even a "sorry to see you go."
- Discussions like [Are there specific issues with unwelcoming behavior toward LGBTQ persons on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334058/are-there-specific-issues-with-unwelcoming-behavior-toward-lgbtq-persons-on-stac/) and [How can the community assist in welcoming LGBTQ users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334107/how-can-the-community-assist-in-welcoming-lgbtq-users) have already put a heavy burden on marginalized users to continually justify themselves, when the CM team could be helping to facilitate that discussion more productively.

I do not believe anyone should be misgendered on a SE site, and subject to community discussion and guidance about how specifically that should work in practice for the types of interactions we have on the site, I support Stack Exchange's commitment to making that happen, especially knowing it will not please everyone. And I recognize that this policy was apparently unfinished, which is why it had not been announced yet, except it now seems to have been announced in an official statement to The Register.

**But it is upsetting to me that Stack Exchange staff would speak about this to the press before addressing their own community**. SE has a lot of communication channels: meta, ~174 site metas, the blog, chat, that cool new newsletter announced today, email blasts, featured posts, Twitter. What is the use of all of these communication methods if official information is provided to the press instead of being shared directly with the community?

I can certainly appreciate that engaging on Meta is difficult for SE staff right now, and that even more broadly than this incident, it has resulted in staff being at the receiving end of stuff they shouldn't have to experience in the workplace. So I can understand why it seems easier to provide a quote to a reporter than it is to respond substantively here. But there's a destructive message sent by providing more information to the press than to the site's own users, a message that Stack Exchange is uninterested in actually speaking with its own community.

If Stack Exchange is interested in addressing *waves hands variously at all this*, that needs to start with direct communication with the site's users. Speaking through the press will not help.

Comment: SE seems to be chasing a really fast dog right now.

Comment: @Snow - I felt that a better metaphor would be 'shooting itself in the foot, then stopping to reload'. Demodding her was bad, but their response (crappy terse boilerplate meta responses, throwing shade at her in the press) has been nothing short of incompetence

Comment: My guess is they're working on a comprehensive response to here and haven't finished that. I agree then speaking to the press is bad timing.

Comment: @magisch timing won't have been driven by them though but by a request for comment. And they get the opportunity to provide their own narrative of welcome and inclusion. They would have been stupid not to take it.

Comment: I'm just disgusted with the way Stack Exchange is behaving these days.

Comment: And don't lose the irony that, aside from any untruths or misdirections that could be argued - the SE comment explicitly misgendered Monica, the very thing they claim she was fired for (though she never actually did). Monica has stated often that she is a she, and she is offended by being called they. This hamfisted statement does not seem accidental, but spiteful.

Comment: It's their right to talk or not to talk with whoever they like or not like. I don't see any moral obligation to talk to the community about recent incidents at all or to talk about it before they talk to the press or anything else. It's one of the fundamental tasks of the Press to inform people about issues, so talking to the Press is kind of a reasonable move. Partly this sounds a bit like bruised collective ego.

Comment: @AviD I don't see that. Yes, they start of by saying "one Stack Exchange moderator when they ...," but that's before they say it's Monica (so when they're attempting to hide her identity). However, when they do mention her name, her preferred pronoun is given: "Cellio **(she/her)** would not ..."

Comment: Shouldn't it say "... ***they*** would not use stated pronouns ...", otherwise we'd have to go back and edit as often as change is permitted. Maybe it could change on it own, spin like a wheel or flash like the AD on Music.SE. --- I always try to use or leave out rather than being specific, what do  think? They must make several choices on the User Profile so it can be live updated.

Comment: "would not use stated pronouns, which violates our current CoC"... wait, WHAT? The **current** CoC? Where? How? When? Why?

Comment: @muru that's why it looks spiteful. It was not a mistake or lack of attention, it was fully mindful. The state her pronouns, but will not refer to her with them. Which is exactly what she was accused of.

Comment: @AviD I don't know. My understanding is that Monica would have preferred to do something like "muru wrote a comment. muru said foo ..." instead of "muru wrote a comment. Xe said foo ..." (not saying that xe is my preferred pronoun or that Monica objects to "xe", just an example), whereas in the article, there never arose a need for a pronoun for Monica after she was referred to by name. She is referred to directly in only sentence. I think it's likely that if a pronoun was reasonably needed, they would have used she/her, *because* they clarified the pronoun after the initial concealing "they".

Comment: Has anybody tried reaching out to SO through a Twitter account with cool-people influencer credentials but visibly zero investment in Stack Overflow except some expressions of disdain? Chances are a full statement will be forthcoming within 15 minutes 

Comment: @muru I guess I'm reading it that way because I just read the whole initial argument... Well, and because I have a several kids under the age of 10.

Comment: @muru "muru wrote a comment. muru said foo ..." or "muru wrote a comment and said foo..." or "a comment was written by muru. it said foo...". There are so many possibilities to convey meaning without using third person pronouns. I really wonder if StackOverflow really wants to force people to use them? I guess that would be very difficult. Something like: We detected that you did not use pronouns for a while. If you do not improve we will ban you for a certain time.

Comment: @Trilarion Apparently, going out of your way to avoid using the third person pronoun is discrimination as well.

Comment: @JAD I give it a year and not showing up will be seen as discrimination too.

Comment: So, they confirmed, that Monica was resigned just for asking questions. Am I right? o_O

Comment: @Suvitruf who confirmed? That's pretty obvious from first-handed witnesses, from what I can tell. They won't lie about it.

Comment: @Shadow there are a lot of speculations around this situation )=

Comment: @Suvitruf the correct word here isn't '*resigned*' but '*fired*'.

Comment: "*a message that Stack Exchange is uninterested in actually speaking with its own community*" - There is nothing really new in this statement.

Comment: I'd also add that the quote, "Cellio (she/her) would not use stated pronouns, which violates our current CoC. We are soon publishing an update to the CoC to even more explicitly cite misgendering users or moderators as a violation," strongly implies that Monica was actively using the wrong pronouns, which is patently false and borderline libelous.

Comment: I notice that the comments in this and other threads are now no longer deleted aggressively. That's a great thing.

Answer (score 40):

I can't say that this decision really surprises me.

Right now, the Meta network is trying to deal with the fallout that's happened over the weekend, and admittedly there's a **lot** of tension and animosity about this circumstance.

There's several factions at play here:

- Those loyal to what Monica has pioneered on the site, and who are disgusted at the way she was treated;
- Those who oppose the changes to the CoC (which haven't been made public just yet);
- Those who are frustrated with the lack of communication in general from Stack Overflow Inc., and are treating this as the proverbial last straw;
- Stack Exchange staff, who have a duty to keep their house in order;
- ...and those who are just caught up in the mess.

Right now, ***none*** of those factions see eye-to-eye with one another, and are kind of just...shouting.  Like, shouting really loudly.  The decisions to resign and the decisions to suspend activity are adding more voices to the conversation, but the issue has become less and less cohesive overall.

Admittedly, Stack Overflow Inc. [really has dropped the ball on communication](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318341/175248) when it comes to things like this...but it's not made any better by the fact that now we're all tooled up and ***angry*** about the circumstances.

If you know that you have a specific message to deliver, do you *really* want to deliver it to a hostile crowd who'd sooner tear your head from your shoulders than hear you out?  Personally, I wouldn't.

But that's the *easy* choice.  The reality of it is that the lack of communication has been a regrettable symptom of what's happened to the network, the volunteers who help, and the staff who have to keep the lights on.  And I maintain that **suddenly appearing and communicating with us will not actually make this better.**  We're still holding the pitchforks, after all.

So at a minimum, I suppose I'm happy that some staff member in some back-channel way at least commentated to the effect of what we kind of suspected the issue was in the first place. I doubt that's going to make anyone really happy about what's happened, but I don't know what else we're going to expect at this point.  Honestly, while I believe in miracles, I don't think I'm going to hold out faith that there will *ever* be an official announcement.

I'd be delighted to be demonstrated wrong, though.

Comment: Surely, all the posts I've read from you cannot be wrong -- you're smart enough to understand that at this stage in the process, there is a new CEO who's supposed to stand up roughly right now, and they will have a lot to deal with. Removing Sara from the equation would be quite tempting at this juncture, which is why I wonder why they have not added two plus two and already resigned by now.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  ...by doing that, you've successfully made a public scapegoat of your own employee, and introduced a chilling effect on the company when you want to march forward with a new directive, which may be important to the company's goals.  That's **just as bad**.

Comment: I don't think so, really. So-called "fuses" have always existed in politics, and that's politics we're talking about right now, isn't it?

Comment: "Right now, none of those factions see eye-to-eye with one another, and are kind of just...shouting." I'd actually say that there's a lot of overlap between group 2 (object to CoC) and 3 (communication issues), and a lot of those are also in group 1 (object to Monica's treatment).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  It kinda goes deeper than that.  The immediate and knee-jerk reaction is to have someone step down/be removed from their post.  I don't see that as being a good thing since I genuinely do believe that they're trying to deliver on their promises, and the delivery might leave much to be desired, depending on who you talk to.  This also isn't a political position, so I'd rather not draw parallels to that if I can.

Comment: @Makoto, it kinda goes *even* deeper than that. The immediate and knee-jerk reaction *of the SE staff* was to have *Monica* removed ASAP. Within that reasoning, I don't see why removing Sara would be better or worse.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  I see that you still have your pitchfork ready to go.   I respect your attachment to it, but now is the time for calmer heads and calmer discussion to prevail.

Comment: @Kevin:  I find myself in camps 1, 2, 3 and 5.  I was totally blindsided on a peaceful Sunday afternoon when I found out what happened.  My wording may have been heavier handed than I wanted it to be, but ultimately...there's several different messages that need to be delivered to *all* of the above camps, and those messages aren't the same messages and won't have the same impact.  Reconciling how this communication needs to be done is no easy feat.  Whoever has to step up to the plate to deliver it - I hope that they have their favorite antacid at the ready.

Comment: @Makoto, *touché*. Back on-topic, I sincerely don't believe for a second the new CEO will step in under the current conditions without doing something, *anything*, to improve them. And, well, even though there are many different interests already fighting in there, all of them have pretty designated targets... To be blunt, I do not believe one second in the *Bigots vs Queers* fights we're being told about, and I am very worried about the repercussions of this.

Comment: @Kevin:  I do however see the disagreement over what the CoC will eventually entail as orthogonal to the fact that Stack Overflow Inc. has failed to really communicate with us about what's going on.  At the most, it's yet another symptom.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi:  This entire answer has been trying to quantify "improve".  The only real conclusion I've reached is that there is no real improvement to be had here.  No one is going to go home happy about any of this.  The best that can happen is that the company owns on it and them moves on.  Whether or not we choose to move *with* them is another matter altogether.  It would be **unwise** for the CEO to just jump into this blind.

Comment: You forgot to mention the point of misgendering and making someone resign due to there queerness.

Comment: @AnkitSharma:  No, I'm pretty sure I *explicitly* left that off.  It's a detail that in all actuality **doesn't matter** right now since the symptoms that we're dealing with as a result of the fallout are a lot worse - and when the new CoC becomes public we might learn more about what's going on.

Comment: @AnkitSharma:  It's just...orthogonal to the situation we have at hand, IMO.  People have always been grumpy on Meta.  The reason for why they're grumpy changes with the seasons.  The real next thing that matters is how we pick up the pieces.

Comment: @Makoto it started with that only where some people denied someone's right to be addressed in the way they are comfortable for there rigidness of someone's writing style.

Comment: @AnkitSharma:  And yet, on a technical network site, from which I hail from...that is literally noise to the question one may ask.  Neither the program nor the compiler/interpreter care what pronoun you want to use.  It's also irrelevant when you're asking about threading or how to sort an array.  I don't have any context into this as an "issue" since on the technical sites, we don't get into that stuff or broach the topic.  On the non-technical sites, I could clearly see how it's an issue.  But none of that has to do with Meta literally being on fire right now.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: We have tons of resignations - some in solidarity, some over the actual language of the CoC.  There are valid concerns which exist on how to enforce this policy and to what degree it needs to be exercised under.  There are valid discussions that need to take place when it comes to what sites should apply this more readily than others because **this really isn't a universal, network-wide problem**.  Some are *making* it into one, but having been on SO for years, I've yet to see it bubble up to become A Problem™.

Comment: @AnkitSharma:  For that reason, I politely request that we simply not talk about it.  That's not the point of this question, nor is it the point of this answer.

Comment: @Makoto I will say first read the question again then you will know the context better and second it's better if you have full context before answering.

Comment: @Makoto and your answer ony for enetrtaining oen fraction and fine with what happening to otehr fraction as eitehr you don't acre about it or you don't mind as long as you are not teh one suffering. -1 for incomlete answer on purpose. Peace  \o/

Comment: Agree that the new CEO stepping in and firing Sara would be bad for the company both internally and externally - setting precedent that company execs are beholden to the meta crowd is a great way to handicap your company. At the same time, I do think they would be wise to work with the community, even when they disagree about the direction the network should go.  The best case scenario would probably be for Sara to apologize publicly to Monica or some kind of compromise statement - similar to how Bob Iger handled the James Gunn situation.

Comment: That would let both sides bury the hatchet and move on.

Comment: Thanks for this plea of politeness and civility. Something I long been waiting to hear in this discussion. I too understand that people are angry, and want heads to roll. It shows just how much we are attached to this site, and the users that make it work. However burning the house down right now leaves us nothing more then a pile of ashes. Not something I desire.

Comment: @Makoto, I think your missing out on one bit regarding the pronoun issue. You are certainly right that a compiler doesn't care, and that it is irrelevant for writing questions and answers. However there also exist comments on this site, and those don't always tend to be polite. Also there is the case where moderators have to convey a message towards a certain user. It would be nice if the desired pronouns would be used then. Albeit I think the network is making a bigger point out of this whole deal. The rule could simply be we use singular they on everyone. No discrimination then.

Comment: Overall a good summary, but with all due respect, _SE has done a lot more_ than just "shout loudly" by banning a moderator for no wrongdoing on her part, ignoring their own code of conduct and telling different parties different versions of the story, such as "we don't share details" (with the community) but happily sharing details with a much wider audience via the press.

Comment: "Reconciling how this communication needs to be done is no easy feat." I'm not even sure that's true. You've done a great job breaking down the "camps". I don't think it would be that hard for SO to say (and I _guess_ this is what they've been working so hard on): 1. We clearly messed up in the way the Monica situation was handled. [either release details of the alleged CoC violation or state unequivocally that no such details will be released by SO] 2. [release new CoC, with clarifications] 3. [repeat boilerplate 'we've got to do better' communications]