# Has Stack Exchange made anything approaching a clear or detailed statement on the current crisis?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Over the past few days, a great many Meta sites for various sites in the Stack Exchange network have been lit up by publicized moderator resignations and some dismissals.

Most of these have blamed a vaguely-defined trend of unilateral bureaucratic action by SE staff. Some others have had other motivations -- for example, [Monica (Judaism)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel/5197#5197) and [Caleb (Christianity)](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel/5197#5197) cited a demand for strict, affirmative adherence to a particular standard for discussing gender and use of pronouns with no room for discussion or alternatives, [Aza (Literature)](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/resignation-notice) by contrast complained that they felt variously unwelcomed and put-upon by what they characterized as a steady stream of individually low-intensity anti-queer bigotry. (However, almost none of the high-profile moderator resignation or dismissal posts have been very detailed.)

As a result of this, Stack Exchange is clearly in crisis with some major sites having few or no active moderators.

It often appears that all of these questions, reports, complaints, etc. on various meta sites are linked to each other; following these links [rarely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper) provides much background, though a few bureaucratic non-responses from SE staff (often downvoted into negative hundreds) have shown up.

I am a very casual user of Stack Exchange and rarely have insight into internal politics that many power users seem to consider obvious. Indeed, I believe this is the first time that I have made any action at all on any SE Meta site. I wish it were under happier circumstances.

**Has Stack Exchange made *any* statement about this crisis which has crippled their moderator corps and probably driven away many of the strongest contributors? Either on Stack Exchange or by any other channel? Has anybody publicly discussed internal politics of Stack Exchange's response to the crisis?**

Comment: No, not as such. Well, other than this [copy-pasted boilerplate answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389908).

Comment: @Blue is that only on StackExchange itself, or also including any other way the company or its staff might communicate?

Comment: There's also this: [Stack Exchange staff speaking to the press instead of the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334133/stack-exchange-staff-speaking-to-the-press-instead-of-the-community)

Comment: I guess we will see how it develops in the next few days.

Comment: Even high reputation users don't know all of what is going on as most of it is in discussions that only moderators and staff can see.

Comment: Man, and I thought that Reddit moderation politics was a total mess.

Comment: Now, yes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology, but I guess you've seen it. I'm linking here for reference.

Comment: @dim: What you linked to is certainly not detailed, and not entirely clear IMO.

Comment: @einpoklum Does it make it irrelevant? That's all we have that looks like a statement from SE. I just wanted this to be linked to the post, I certainly didn't want to trigger yet another debate.

Comment: @dim: Not irrelevant, but the answer to this question is still "no".

Comment: Don't respect your users, and one day the karma strike...