# Is it appropriate for new/unaware members know what a controversy is about?

Tags: discussion

After a long gap away from SE, I have returned to find innumerable requests to reinstate someone.

As you can imagine my curiosity is piqued but, more importantly, I would like to know enough to form an opinion about the matter.

Clearly this concerns what journalists would describe as "*public interest*" - indicating that publication may be justified even at the cost of betraying some confidences.

It seems that the matter is already out in the open but without those in the know explicitly describing the events.

Is it acceptable to ask what happened and why?

Comment: Well... [here is a start](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)

Comment: @VLAZ - Phew, I wasn't expecting *that*!

Comment: You can find a lot of information from this Google searchy: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=stack+exchange+the+monica+situation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 There are a few meta posts and an interview with the fired mod.

Comment: [Related meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334399/269301)

Comment: Beware. It's a rabbit hole ...

Comment: How could that not be appropriate, unless you're advocating censorship?