# What did Monica do to violate the CoC?

Tags: discussion, moderators, community, code-of-conduct

[According to SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology), they

> removed a moderator for repeatedly violating our existing Code of Conduct and being unwilling to accept our CM’s repeated requests to change that behavior.

As [Monica says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526),

> Representatives of the company including executives, a director, and the Community Management team have failed to respond to my repeated requests to be shown these alleged violations and warning...

So, what did Monica actually *do*?

---

#### Previous content so comments make sense:

**What did Monica say, according to SO?**

What did Monica actually say that [violated the existing Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology) (pending Monica's acceptance, of course)? We've heard a lot about how she *did*, but not *what* she did.

Comment: Secret, it seems.

Comment: @Stormblessed Hence, "pending Monica's acceptance".

Comment: Monica is communicating with SE at the moment. My best guess is that we'll know something if SE decides to reply to the reply to the initial email.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl I think this should be open knowledge, regardless.

Comment: @gadzooks02 Maybe, but the communication channel is currently dead.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Why have we heard from them, then?

Comment: I would hardly call what's happened so far "hearing from them". They've already lied in the third apology (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335133/332043), Monica stated SE isn't replying (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/332043), and none of the other concerns have been answered.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl By definition, them saying _anything_ is us hearing from them.

Comment: **Short answer**: we don't know, and those who know are not likely to discuss it in public.

Comment: I also said "communication" in my first message, which is what I based my message on. But even then, I still stand by my words - they're not talking about the things the community sees as important, and there's no communication. There's the periodic announcements, the only place I've seen active staff is in reply to some posts on the CoC FAQ, but there's still a *ton* that goes unaddressed. The only communication beyond that is between members, and internally in the company - nothing between the two.

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334214/369403). The chat log won't be made public, so we can't know what Monica said in context, and out of context it won't be of much use.

Comment: As others have pointed out, we mods are not allowed to share transcripts or screenshots from mod-only space.  Monica herself [has posted](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel) about what went down and there are details in many other locations as well.  The long and short of it is that there wasn't anything more than what's been reported in SE space that all users can read.  There was no big statement, there was no pointed refusal, and there was no violation of the CoC as written at the time.

Comment: I have not been told, despite repeated requests for that information.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Would you be opposed to publicly posting all communication that _may_ be relevant? Anonymizing their names as appropriate, of course. SE wouldn't like it, but if they refuse to communicate, that's the only option available.

Comment: @jhpratt need to understand the claims first. There was some deeply personal stuff in some of the pre-firing email (yeah, misplaced trust -- oops), so I don't want to publish it *if that's not the problem*, which it apparently isn't. They claim I violated the CoC; CoC violations are by definition on-site actions; therefore we can start there with them telling us what *exactly* was a violation in that TL discussion. The TL transcript was already leaked to Reddit and I saw nothing that *I* did there to violate the CoC. I assume others have looked too. That's the place to start, I think.

Comment: There's also the question of urgency; I left TL on Sep 18 and didn't speak again until just after being fired (briefly, before being kicked).  I don't think I made any posts or comments on the team.  My activity on Q&A sites was normal -- and anyway, if I'd done something wrong on one of the sites, that site's mods would have handled it.  Somehow, though, it was urgent that they fire me on Sep 27.  I still don't know why.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ok! I wasn't sure of the location of the alleged violations. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Are we allowed to ask who, or what role, did the firing?  Also, did it seem to be done quickly in anger (as a parent might rashly shout, "You're grounded for a month!"), or something that had been thought through and discussed with others? I'm sorry if these seem like nosy or painful questions (I'm afraid you may not be able to do much answering, partly from *being in the dark*), but I feel that the entire SE community is colossally stuck, unable to move in any direction, with the confusion and uncertainty related to what happened to you.  I feel like I don't know what...

Comment: ... hit me (us), and I suppose that may be the primary feeling you are having. // Also, I am wondering, now that you've had a chance to see the new CoC and supporting docs and the reassurance from @jnat (which is nice to hear, but doesn't seem to jive with SE's behavior toward you), is there anything that you would change now about how you would describe your views about singular third-person pronoun use? Either as a garden variety participant, or as a moderator?  You don't have to answer any of these questions -- you've been thoroughly pummeled already -- but if you're game, I'm curious. Thx.

Comment: @aparente001 a manager on the CM team sent the email, though it sounds like the decision was made farther up.  The email didn't seem hastily-written.  *I* perceived no urgency; I hadn't been in TL in more than a week, was just doing normal stuff on my sites, and *bam*, fired.  I've heard rumors that SE thought it was urgent but I don't know why.  As for the CoC, it looks like they made some important changes since (as a result of?) that TL discussion and mandatory speech isn't a requirement now, but the FAQ confuses things so it's hard to tell.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Thanks for laying it out. // I feel completely stuck.  I need the company to explain what happened, from their point of view, and I'd like you to be offered reinstatement, or else a very good reason why not.  Without this, I don't feel that I can trust the company not to do random, irrational, hurtful things.  That is, I feel like I'm balancing on an ice floe that is melting at an unpredictable rate.  It seems many other people feel similarly unsettled. // If the company doesn't engage in a true dialogue with you by some specific date, would you be willing to give mediation...

Comment: ... a try?  It costs $250 and you don't have to travel. JAMS told me that Stack Overflow would either have to come to you or conduct the mediation by phone or in writing -- assuming the mediator agrees to the alternative method.  I am confident that at least 250 participants here would happily chip in $1 for a mediation to take place -- then you wouldn't need to pay the fee out of pocket.  I have experience encouraging a school district to enter into a mediation. It's often helpful to tell the other side something like this: *I've been waiting patiently for the promised dialogue to begin, ...*

Comment: ... *but I'm getting discouraged.  I hope we may begin by [date -- e.g. 10/17/19].  The only alternative course of action that I am aware of would be to file for arbitration with JAMS, Inc., with a request for mediation, as provided for in the terms of service.  However, I would prefer to have a more informal dialogue.  I look forward to hearing from you soon.*

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I've created a new room: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1378/recapping-personal-discussion.  If you have time, I hope you and Colleen will join me there.  I think I've understood most of what you wrote on Friday, after going over the text carefully, and I'd like to check my understanding.

Comment: It looks like people are closing this as "off-topic" somehow. Suggested edit: instead of asking what did she *say*, which might be confidential, ask *"In what way exactly did she break the rules?",* which is something any sane company should publish if they believe the decision was right, so that others know what to do and not do.

Comment: @Cyn There was a statement that was a politely worded refusal (I understand that the content of the statement could be construed as hurtful, but the attempt was made to not be hostile), but it was from over a year ago.

Comment: @ColleenV Nodding.  My feeling is that if they are claiming she broke the current CoC then it was also current a year ago, yet there was no action or hint of action.  I get the opinion of "your way of wanting to handle this and your explanations are not good" but how that goes from zero (for over a year!) to "you're fired" with no warnings of any kind, is just mind boggling.  Something is happening behind the scenes we're not privy to.

Comment: @ColleenV - I don't understand (sorry).  Was that statement specifically intended for Monica?  Or for someone else in a similar situation?  Or something else?  Thanks.

Comment: @aparente001 There was a conversation in the TL chat room over a year ago that could be technically pointed at to support some of the accusations leveled at Monica, but having read that statement in context, I believe that to be some very thin ice to support demodding a moderator without due process.

Comment: @ColleenV over a *year* ago?  There's been so much stuff in TL since then that has been *way* more blatant than anything I said then, like direct personal attacks that likely led to another mod quitting, so if they're dumpster-diving in the transcript, there are bigger problems.  Wow, I assumed they were talking about something recent, especially since they claim I did something wrong after being warned by a CM (and I don't recall any CM warnings from back then, though without access to the transcript I'm hobbled).

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I agree, citing ancient history makes whatever case against you they might think they have seem very suspect.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Like you, I don't know which actual chat messages were considered the actual violation - there was only one statement a year ago I could find that was a direct refusal to use "they". And I do think you were unfairly singled out.

Comment: @ColleenV yeah, I probably said that a year ago, but it's hardly the last thing I said on the subject.  If that's what they're acting on, then they're cherry-picking to target me while ignoring much worse from others.

Comment: OK, if no one has any objections, I'm going to edit this to "What did Monica do to violate the CoC", since this is heavily related and _not_ likely to be close-voted.

Comment: @gadzooks02 - I don't have sufficient rep to see how many close votes there are; that sounds to me like it would be a helpful edit.

Comment: @aparente001 Four and five are needed to close :)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Hoping you'll take a look at my recap of your stance and provide feedback, or edit it.  I'll also willingly delete the post entirely if that's what you prefer.  Here it is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335715/287826

Comment: @aparente001 my recap is on my blog.  My Mi Yodeya meta post contains direct links.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I have read your blog, and other things; I'm confused, and hoping you can provide some feedback, in the format and venue that work best for you.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - The thing is, I don't want to weigh in and respond to your stance yet -- that wouldn't be fair, without the opportunity to check my understanding first.  We were starting to work on that but you had to step out and then there was no resumption.

Comment: @Monica Cellio Can you think of any incident in which you may have personally offended (however inadvertently) the SE staff member who fired you? (Sarah? Sorry, can't remember her name.)  Is is possible that all this hoo-ha is is about malicious revenge instead of the high-minded issue that SE is making it out to be?

Comment: @ab2 could be; I've no idea.  The person who sent the email probably did not make the decision.  I barely knew who Sara was before that day in TL, but she probably didn't like being challenged (she has a [history](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) of not dealing well with feedback).  But I've argued against other policies over the years too, and spoke up about the HNQ debacle, so who knows who at SE might be harboring a personal dislike of me and looking for any excuse to wield it? Malice is quite possible, but unproven.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it irrelevant what she is accused of at this point. It just muddies the water more and more to bring it up. Her situation is just a symptom of the greater issue.

Comment: @SomeoneWhoUsedToCare, that isn't a reason for it being off-topic, however. I don't think anything can be really off-topic in Meta unless it belongs on one of the other network sites.

Comment: @SomeoneWhoUsedToCare In the unlikely event that it turns out that Monica did repeatedly and unambiguously break the previous CoC, the flavour of the discourse would change dramatically. Moreover, "meta is for Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Overflow, the company" - straight from http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta . I find it difficult to see how this is off-topic. Unlikely to get a productive response? Certainly. But not off-topic.

Comment: Isn't it true that the updated CoC wasn't released yet? Wouldn't the answer be nothing even if what they said was true (which it isn't)?

Comment: gadzooks02: Please consider accepting @mxyzpl's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335752/196834).

Answer (score 243):

She didn’t do anything to violate the CoC.

Given leaked transcripts some have seen and been unable to identify CoC violations, and many mods here from the TL also not being able to identify any clear violations, and no one being able to come up with anything that was not either customary in the TL or "pre-thoughtcrime" concerns of "maybe she won't follow the future CoC", the clear reason the “CoC violation” has not been shared is that there was not one.  The claim that there was a violation is simply cover for getting rid of a voice bold enough to disagree with an SE employee’s plans.

And of course when threatened with legal action [they released a statement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio) saying "whoops, it was a mistake." (A mistake they took unilateral and extreme action on, refused feedback, and refused to undo went unsaid.)

In the end the only CoC that applies to this situation is the whim of people like Sara and David.  They see no need to justify their removal of a voice they found annoying with anyone here; their contempt for meta, mods, CMs, and the larger community has been made amply clear through many communications and actions over these months in late 2019 and early 2020.

If anyone saw Monica clearly violate the CoC, feel free to say so; you don’t have to share the secret TL details.  **But no one has, so the obvious answer is that it did not happen.**

I don't know why it's not obvious to people in the world that when people make claims that lack specific details, proof, witnesses, or substantiation of any sort that it's just a garden variety lie, but for some reason people have trouble getting their heads around that. But given not a shred of evidence from any of these sources, it's clear that the claims that Monica violated the CoC is simply a convenient ginned up statement designed to provide a veneer of legitimacy to an otherwise arbitrary and dictatorial move, to fragment opposition and ablate the effects of their actions somewhat in the community.  Because of course you can't prove a negative, so the deck is already stacked against a claim of innocence (except for those of us that live in places that believe in "innocent until proven guilty").

Comment: This answer is not accurate. There is at least one moderator who says they have seen the not public evidence and agree with Monica's removal, even though none have said they agree with how she was removed. Example: "I support that Monica was removed -- I understand the reasons behind it and with the evidence I saw it made sense" -- [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390427/im-resigning-as-a-stack-overflow-community-elected-moderator#comment734781_390430). I personally don't think that if I saw the evidence I would agree though, I highly doubt Monica did anything wrong.

Comment: Those folks are welcome to contribute a compelling answer then.

Comment: No, they literally are not welcome to do that. The moderators are not to "leak transcripts" as you put it. The corporation has to communicate it directly to Monica in private, and give *her* the option of publicizing the results, and when she does, publicly state that her account is correct. If someone, even with good intentions, tried to post whatever "convincing evidence" they have, that would only serve to drag Monica's name further through the mud, and for no reason.

Comment: Far too many people have spoken for Monica already without her getting any reasonable avenue to respond (Even with hundreds of people here who know there's no public evidence, news outlets have made her look like a bigot in ways that are causing actual harm to her, and no meta post or blog can combat that) . The next thing said out of this must come from her, no one else. (Unless of course SE wants to say "Sorry, we seriously screwed up, Monica did absolutely nothing wrong" and start making some actual amends.)

Comment: @DavyM: The quote you gave by George Stoker does not cite any article of the CoC which was removed, nor provide evidence that it had been violated.

Comment: @DavyM, the rest of that comment seems rather important too (emphasis mine): "However, and this is the crux of my issue: The manner in which Monica was removed (not adhering to existing process; **not following any semblance of due process; not clearly articulating the problematic behavior and the consequences of the problematic behavior**; not being very clear about the next steps to all, and publicly saying thing that shouldn't have been said) forms the basis for me being quite concerned about any proposed process. SO Inc hasn't fixed existing issues."

Comment: I don’t know if I would go so far as to say Monica didn’t violate the CoC. I would say she was unfairly singled out for behavior that was tolerated when other mods did it. Whatever could be construed as CoC violations happened in a private chat room where SE had allowed an environment that led people to believe we weren’t really “on duty” in there, so I wouldn’t have expected a disagreement in there to lead to anyone being demodded unless they were threatening violence or something equally serious and malicious.

Comment: @ColleenV - I like what you wrote about the unfair singling out. // Maybe these questions have been asked before, if so please link or give me a clue what to look for.  What were the non-CoC behaviors that occurred in the TL, did you see it for yourself (from Monica, or from others) in the TL, is the TL still a place where those behaviors occur, or could occur, and what if anything is being done about the problem?  Apologies if I'm asking something again that I already asked you.  (Would it be better to write a question?) Thanks.

Comment: @aparente001 I can’t share any of those details. What I wrote is my impression from my personal experience. Other people may interpret it differently.

Comment: @ColleenV - Thanks.  What do you think, is the TL still the Wild West I'm getting the impression it was?  If so, do you have any ideas about how to solve that problem?

Comment: You can't very well say both "feel free to say so, you don't need to provide details from TL" and then dismiss someone saying so because they didn't provide details from TL.

Comment: I see no answer here indicating she did something wrong (I mean, some kind of description of what would be lovely of course).  There's someone citing in a comment someone else's vague comment on an answer on another question.  That's not very helpful.  Someone should post an answer saying "Yes, on day X in TL (or other venue) I saw Monica make statements that I felt were violations of the CoC and grounds for removal as a moderator." Then other mods with that access could say "yes, I agree" or "yes, she violated the CoC but in a minor way not really meriting removal" or something else.

Comment: But random third-hand rumor - yes, I'm going to dismiss it, as should you.

Comment: A summary from a mod is not "random third-hand rumor", it's exactly what you asked for. But as of present day there is no point; SE and Monica have reached their agreement and nothing anyone says on meta matters.

Comment: He's welcome to post an answer.

Comment: Also, If I recall correctly a member was against Monica. I think their username starts with All Philosophers or something like that following a "Hate Monica" or maybe it was reinstate Monica and I'm in mistake.

Comment: Is that CoC implemented now, or it went out of the window after the controversies?

Answer (score -271):

We don't discuss these things publicly.

Comment: Isn't the rule: "we don't discuss these things publicly unless the other party wants it made public"? Which in this case Monica appears to want that.

Comment: Could you at the very least discuss it with Monica then?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder looks like there are more people involved, not just Monica, and they don't want it public.

Comment: And neither in private, according to Monica's [updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/223820), she still hasn't received any clarification. Was she not owed one?

Comment: @Shadow I was under the impression is was "SE and Monica" but I suppose there might be other parties involved.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder even inside SE. The people working for SE are still, well, people. And it took me too long to remember this, for which I feel sorry.

Comment: Well, you must discuss these things publicly. So please do.

Comment: @Shadow Sure and I'm not dismissing that but this is more of a company and individual thing rather than individuals and individual thing if that makes sense.

Comment: That's great for future instances but given that in this case info was divulged even to a newspaper, and from the outside it looks like that info was incorrect and it was an unjust dismissal, this isn't good enough, Stack Overflow Inc. Especially since her case seems to be the splinter that keeps on causing inflammations of community anger.

Comment: Ok.  So this degree of cover-up and lack of any evidence basically confirms the reason is nothing any community member would identify as a breach of the real CoC, it’s just an internal “we didn’t like her” SE staff reason they don’t feel they need to justify.

Comment: SE doesn't want to talk in _public_, nor in _private_ .. there aren't that many access modifiers left :s

Comment: @dfhwze: `internal`, `protected`....

Comment: @Cerbrus, I like `protected internal` myself. Only classes derived from SE staff and residing in the same assembly have access to that information.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I hope you will understand that the downvote isn't against you personally. But the company already discussed this publicly - with a news site.

Comment: @Atizs This article: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just a bald faced lie given that SE Inc *already went to the news* with these things.  You can't get much more public than that.  How do you expect to rebuild trust with the community when you keep lying to us in such obvious ways?

Comment: @NateStrickland It sounds like they had no policy before, but they've codified one in response to this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335749/388335

Comment: @JJJ, Fear and intimidation aren't a great way to get people to do free work for you, which is something Stack Exchange absolutely depends on in order to function.  If they want people to keep contributing free content for them, it would benefit them to make clear that they don't plan to betray those people later.  I suppose that would fall under 'not do business with them' but I'm giving them a chance to fix things before I walk away, and I'm sure I'm not alone in doing so.

Comment: @divibisan, then, it's still a lie that they don't discuss these things publicly, because they literally just did, and only make a policy against that after the damage was done.  Perhaps they do not discuss things like this publicly *anymore*, but it's hardly a reason for them not to discuss this case publicly.  As it stands now, they told their side of the story to a reporter, and then when their story was challenged, they are like 'ah sorry, we never discuss these things so we can't answer'.

Comment: @JJJ I hope you didn’t interpret my bitter comment as coming from SE in some way. I’m just a site mod who is drafting the resignation letter she might need depending on how all this turns out... I’m pretty sure no one at SE would say that out loud (regardless of whether or not they were thinking it).

Comment: @JJJ I stand by it - it’s what I tell myself every time I get tricked into an emotional attachment to something that is for-profit ;) You should read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335868/273494 there’s hope yet...

Comment: "We don't discuss these things publicly" -> "We don't discuss these things" -> "We don't discuss" -> "We don't"

Comment: You have already accused Monica in public. When people ask for public explanations, you suddenly decide you don't do it in public. So which one is it? Will you also in future accuse people in public and then not explain it because you don't discuss in public?

Comment: You have already discussed this in public. Here: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/. Not to mention the meta post accusing her.

Comment: Except in news articles, right?

Comment: I have low expectations of SE these days but this out-and-out lie is just a whole new level of disgraceful.

Comment: "We don't discuss these things publicly." - [I suppose you only discuss these things to the press?](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/08/stack_overflow_apology/)?

Comment: At this point this "answer" could be seen as trolling the community.

Comment: @faintsignal not unless SE speaks with press **again**, after they clearly said they won't do it anymore. If that happens I totally agree, but until then, this answer is valid and to the point, IMO.

Comment: It was discussed in **public** [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5197), [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334248), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551). In all these instances it was very clear who the "offender" was.

Comment: Tim, you're a good person, this is beneath you. At the *very* least you could have the decency to not insult our intelligence and say "We made the mistake of publicly discussing this case in the past, we won't make that mistake again". That wouldn't be satisfactory because a responsible person or company cleans up their mistakes before moving on, but at least it wouldn't be a *blatant* lie. Personally I'd resign rather than make a false statement like this.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard I think it was a mistake to delete BoBoBoBo's answer. If anything, it proved to the naysayers  that Monica's reputation has been harmed. It proved that the allegations without supporting evidence is *harmful* and can have repercussions. But it also showed that the community supports Monica, and we are not intimidated or ashamed to show that support. The comments also demonstrated that the allegations are without substance, and the report in the *The Register* is based on hearsay.

Comment: @Mari-LouA comments are temporary and can be all purged in a moment without a trace. That would leave harmful and misleading answer in place. Downvotes in this case are not enough.