# Can a moderator help me track down the email of a student who copied his homework?

Tags: support

A student copied homework from Stack Overflow. If possible - can a staff member give us his e-mail address so we can contact that individual?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Under what circumstances will Stack Exchange, Inc. share private/sensitive information with the press?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349473/282094) - private information is not shared.

Comment: This question is somewhat odd, if they are your student, then presumably you already possess their contact details. If you mean that you need to know if they wrote the stack-overflow post then ask them. It seems unlikely that a legitimate programming-teacher would be unfamiliar with well-established privacy laws regarding internet sites. This strikes me as less than legitimate. Most likely a  recruitment agency's crude attempt at social engineering to get a client.

Comment: -Cont. or a scammer. Certainly not a teacher.

Comment: In addition to what Ant said, if they copied something _from_ SO and they didn't ask it, what would make you think there's even a record of it. You can't track people not logged on that are copying content

Comment: @ARogueAnt. You'd be surprised how many universities ask for whatever information we can provide on a student. We probably get more of them for our Maths site than for Stack overflow even. Think of it like collecting as much incriminating evidence as possible to build a case in a court room. One piece of evidence may not be enough to prove who it was, but multiple data points can certainly eliminate any doubt. Either way, we would never give out this information.

Comment: @animuson Fair enough, I had no idea, guess I was just reasoning in a vacuum.

Answer (score 30):

No. We do not assist in academic dishonesty investigations, as providing any information about a user that is not available on their profile would violate our Privacy Policy. If you are investigating a student, you will need to do so without assistance from us.