# Does the company claim that every article the press made on ongoing issues wasn't requested by them and was instead an unsolicited initiative?

Tags: discussion

As people continue to comment trying to get me on their side about what is right or wrong to do (and probably voting based on that) I am sadly forced to add this notice to point out what I assumed was already clear.

***This is not a post that aims at judging what has been done nor have I posted this to get someone to convince me of what is happening.***
***The only reasoning behind this post is prompting the company to give their version of the story since the users here only get second-hand reports that are often confused like this was some sort of weird [Chinese whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) game or are simply removed from accessing relevant information that has been discussed privately.***
***The immediate result of this is that every time the current crisis ends, the normal users are left with an incomplete, misguided, and often incorrect view of what the two factions' positions were, what their argumentation was, and so on.***

Deciding what to do with said info is something every user will then have to do on their own.

---

The 2023-06-26 update of Zoe's answer on the "[Moderation Strike update: Data dumps, choosing representatives, GPT data, and where we’re holding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390106/moderation-strike-update-data-dumps-choosing-representatives-gpt-data-and-wh)" contains the following passage.

> Issue: Stack Exchange, Inc. made inappropriate comments to the press
> Progress: We are debating this issue and have not yet reached a conclusion. Stack is so far unwilling to agree to a blanket policy of "no comment" **when asked for comment on anything involving moderators**; we are considering what our options are here.

The bold part seems to imply that the company claims to only have **answered** to requests for comments.

**In my opinion** it doesn't feel quite realistic to think that some random media/press site had caught up some rumors of an ongoing issue on the network and thought that the story was *so interesting* that it was worth to contact the company for comments. It would seem far easier to assume that the company was the one to reach out to the press, in the hope to make its version of the story the most visible one. But obviously I could be wrong.

My question is therefore once again very simple:

**Does the company confirm that every article the press made on ongoing and past issues (examples: Monica, the current moderation strike etc) were not something they requested/paid for but just unsolicited initiatives started by the press?**

Comment: When press writes something, it's very usual to reach out to the affected parties for comments, and in some jurisdictions, there may even be a legal requirement to try to do so (or a legal requirement to publish comments if they're provided after publication, which is why media outlets prefer to have them in advance). It would really surprise me if SE actively sought attention on this issue, but wouldn't surprise me at all if these media outlets approached SE for comments before publication.

Comment: @ErikA sorry, I think exactly the opposite. I would be seriously surprised if any media outlet made the first move to approach the company. Realistically, I doubt "the world" cares enough about Stack Exchange that anyone would see them as a good source for profitable stories. Furthermore that would mean that multiple media outlets lurk on the site waiting for something to happen and write a story for. Seem very unrealistic to me.

Comment: Alas, this is meant as a place for the company to give their own official answer. Deciding on what to make with said answer is something each user will have to do individually, when and if said answer will be given. My point here is just to point out an inconsistency and give the company the opportunity to explain. To take it is they right and their choice.

Comment: The statement looked very much to me like the typical case of a journalist asking the company for comments when writing an article about that company. You usually either see a "company declined to comment" or "company did not respond to requests for comment" or a statement by the company in such articles.

Comment: Journalists don’t just sit around waiting for press releases to drop. They actively go out and look for stories. I don’t think this sort of accusation is productive.

Comment: I dont think its that unreasonable. There are lots of online tech news sites out there and always looking for the next drama that will go viral for them. There was already a reddit thread discussing this issue not long after it started. Its not *that* unbelieveable that some online tech outlets would contact SE about this. I think the only thing is this issue did not become as huge as some people hoped it would be, at least not yet

Comment: "The bold part seems to imply that the company claims to only have answered to requests for comments." I don't understand how you reached that conclusion. Your disclaimer doesn't really help either, as you're very clearly giving an opinion here which people are excercising the right and ability to argue with/against. Not sure if you're expecting 0 engagement aside from staff, but that's not really how this works.

Answer (score 10):

> Stack is so far unwilling to agree to a blanket policy of "no comment" when asked for comment on anything involving moderators...

That does not imply anything about what the company has or has not done. That is a statement about the desired policy from the moderator's perspective. This is likely framed to extend the [existing internal policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349473/273494), which discusses how to deal with press inquiries:

> Authorized Media Representatives should not speak to the press regarding network users or moderators without having received prior written authorization to do so from the subject of the inquiry…Aside from Authorized Media Representatives, no employees or staff should speak with members of the press (in any medium) regarding Stack Overflow customers, network users, or moderators, unless specifically delegated to do so in writing by an Authorized Media Representative. All queries from the media should be forwarded to [an internal email address], and no reply should be given other than "I am forwarding your inquiry to the appropriate contact."