# Why was “What did Monica do to violate the CoC” deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[What did Monica do to violate the CoC?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335373)

Was asking what Monica had done to violate the CoC, the alleged reason for her dismissal.

[Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) briefly posted an answer of [“We don't discuss these things publicly,”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335373/what-did-monica-do-to-violate-the-coc/335804#335804) naturally it started to get downvotes and comments pointing out no reason has been given to Monica, she is OK with sharing it, and the guidance on normal discipline says clearly it’s ok to share some when it’s in the community’s interest.  So he deleted the question outright.

Why?  This could be interpreted as simple silencing of dissent and coverup of inappropriate behavior. Perhaps there is another explanation?

---

## Edit: the question has been undeleted (restored).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Because I have big thumbs and I'm still getting used to the new flag handling interface. I meant to close it, but not delete it, and I'm not certain I know how I actually did that.

This just happened to another mod on another site during a migration of a question.

Something about resolving a flag happening asynchronously and the DOM updating with the appropriate buttons for the next flag seems weird, but I have no idea how I'd reproduce it.

Sorry about that! There weren't any *recent* flags on the question, so I don't know how that button would have popped up. And I've had three cups of espresso so that can't be it.

I undeleted the question, in the meantime.

Comment: You need more practice, clearly....

Comment: But you answered, then closed it. Then time elapsed and more than twenty minutes later the post was deleted? That doesn't look like pressing one button while intending to hit another? If that helps in reconstructing the blooper…

Comment: I have 50 open tabs of stuff that needs attention and half of it deleting, with 150 more urgent flags that need handling. I don't remember deleting the question, but I did, so I clearly did it accidentally. As this had JUST happened to someone else, that's what came to my mind immediately. People are setting things on fire and I'm running after with a bucket and y'all wanna talk about this? I didn't intend to delete the post. Whether I made the mistake when I closed it, or if I had the wrong tab open when I meant to delete something else - _it doesn't matter_.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm afraid Tim is going to have more opportunities to practice flag handling than he ever wanted to have.

Comment: Maybe you should consider getting more mods on MSE? There's currently a massive stream of stuff that needs to be handled, and there's only so much one person can do. Thank you for handling it though - it's needed.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Holding election when a fire is there, make no good. Let's estuinguish that fire and check who is left, and who return, and after lets think to what happen. The why it took so long to fix the fire, only some SE VP hold the cards, so I guess sadly they dont see the CM staff busy atm..

Comment: @yagmoth555 Mods here on MSE are picked, not elected. That can be done in a couple hours assuming timezones work out.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl It will add fuel to the fire, as mod quitted because of that debate. Replace them ? oh well, good luck to them (CM team)

Comment: @yagmoth555 It has nothing to do with "that debate", it's about keeping the site alive while there's still a chance to recover it. If MSE gets more mods, we'll be able to actually handle content posted, and I think the majority of people will be happy about that.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl There wasnt any mod there 6 months ago, and the site was alive. Like I told you, an simple apology or any act from the VP would close that fire anyway..

Comment: @yagmoth555 Yeah, but this isn't 6 months ago. There's a significantly higher volume, and many, many fires that need to be put out. They're trying to fix it, and currently, that's good enough for me. Some things can't be fixed though, and there's no getting around that fact, but we still need to deal with the problems we have *now*. You can't hide it - it's out there, and it'll take effort to get it back under control.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl Ok, I stop the debate, it's offtopic from the post. but appointing new mods, while such action/strike happen, is counterproductive, it will cause more work in the end to Tim.

Comment: Appoint some temporary moderators who are prepared to handle flags

Comment: @TimPost you have to rest sometimes, you know.

Comment: On a related note, you just "purged" a comment of mine in which I told @Xirema that I *don't want them to feel unsafe* because of me expressing unease about the new CoC. The reason you gave was "the comments devolved into the worst that the community has to offer". I don't know if there were comments after mine for which that is true, I just know that I was trying to make that user feel welcome in this community. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335713/how-can-we-resolve-the-current-drama-without-causing-any-more-harm-to-vulnerable#comment1107460_335721)

Comment: @Suvitruf He could just close meta when going off-duty and open it the next day. Or maybe couldn't the company shift duties a bit to have more people here moderating?

Comment: @PoorYorick I understand your frustration, but this is happening more and more lately. Shog9 fully admitted to this. If a comment thread has a large number of flags on the thread, they just purge the entire thread out of efficiency. There simply isn't enough time to sift the gems out from the muck.

Comment: You gave me a smile, thanks @TimPost