# A peculiar justification for closing a post - seeking explanation

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question about [what Monica did to violate the CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335373/what-did-monica-do-to-violate-the-coc) was closed because:

> "This question does not appear to be about the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."

This seems to be a little bit odd to me. The question is definitely about something else but does it mean we now can ask questions only about *software that powers the Stack Exchange network*?

Comment: Reasons for closing are a limited: "This question is attracting too much derailling answers" is not existing, So the CM picked one to be able to concentrate on more pressing actions.

Comment: Oh, did I? Let me fix that.

Comment: There is so much happening and I have like 30 tabs open following everything at the same time.

Comment: Well, technically, that reason fits. The question is not about the __software__ that powers the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335809/why-was-what-did-monica-do-to-violate-the-coc-deleted

Comment: It *should* have been closed. I think *primarily opinion based* would be a better reason, as the violations (or alleged violations, if you'd rather) took place in a private forum and in private e-mails. So all we can do is *speculate*.

Comment: I don't think "this question is attracting too much attention" was ever in itself a legitimate reason for closing. Protecting maybe. And "primarily opinion based" is for questions without an objective answer, not questions where an objective answer exists but is plausibly unsharable. (I do *hope* that SE has a list of specific, unambiguous violations, and I'm sure everyone shares this view)

Comment: ["We don't discuss these things publicly."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335804/102937)

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is not the same question. Not even close.

Comment: @Atizs: Do you have a compelling reason to keep it open?

Comment: Awsome! This question is now a duplicate of the question it asks about. Did we just create a wormhole? @RobertHarvey

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes I do. I went to the duplicate link and the page does not contain an answer to the question asked here.

Comment: @Atizs: Look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/335804/102937).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm sorry.  I submitted a flag requesting assistance with the deletion before you stepped in to help me rescue the question.  It seemed you were interested in getting a better answer.  Perhaps you would like to repost it in some shape or form.  I'm going to work on my Day of Silence post now....

Comment: @aparente001: No need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: everyone wants that question answered and SO has refused to do so in public. It could be reopened by the community in its present state, but it would be no more likely to get an official answer.

Closure doesn't always fit the reason *exactly* either. I wouldn't focus on the reasoning too much here. Tim Post wanted it closed. It's closed. I wouldn't take it as a broader policy thing either, since none of the other Monica-related questions are closed in a similar fashion ([this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335508/monicas-situation-continues-unresolved-is-se-hoping-the-problem-just-goes-away) even got an answer).